# What ways are there to minimize the memory size of images in an android app?

Tags: android, storage

I have a lot of images and some gifs. My apk file is 99.6 megabytes because of this. Currently I'm using webviews and gifs saved in my assets folder to load them and am using images in image viewers. I have put the gifs through optimizers and been resizing images and such to try to lower the size. I don't want to make them so small that the quality diminishes when I make them larger enough to use. What are my other options?

Comment: images and gif can be fetched from the internet as per user interaction that's the best way to reduce apk size

Comment: Are you saying to load them into the application that way? Or to direct them out of the app? Can you elaborate on "as per user interation"?